# Why won't a window take keys sent by sendkeys?

Tags: powershell, automation, installation, sendkeys

I'm trying to build a Powershell script in order to automate an installation of a program I'm using (unfortunatly the program doesn't have a silent installer).
The problem is that the installer window won't take keys sent by sendkeys: if I just hit enter it will work, and sending enter with sendkeys to any other window would work too, but sending enter using sendkeys to that specific installer window won't do anything. Did anyone encounter this problem before and know how to solve it? the script I'm trying to use is as follows:

```
add-type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

./installer.exe

start-sleep 1

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate('select setup language')
start-sleep 1

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~');
```

P.S
it's not a timing issue: I tried changing the sleeping times, but that won't do any good.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the installer elevated while the powershell script is not? Notice that you can't drag and drop (for example) between windows with different privilege levels.

Comment: @briantist - thanks for your comment. I'm not sure I understand what you mean - the installer has focus when the script sends the enter key.

Comment: Does your script running in Administrator mode ? If not please run that script as Administrator privileges even if you are Admin on that system.

Comment: @AjitMedhekar That did it! thanks a lot! (wish I could mark a comment as a solution. it would be great if you add it as an answer so people will see it in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run that script as Administrator. Because many times it happens that even if we are having Admin privileges, the script can not perform the functionality on the winForms or other things. 
So its a good practice to run that script as a Administrator (Run As Administrator).